# PHP Consolidate Inventory into Table

Tags: php, mysql, tabular, inventory

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question to answer.

I have a MySQL Database with the following fields:
   `shoe_size` and `waist_size`

The `shoe_size` entries range anywhere from 3 to 21 (incrementing by halves-- 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, etc).

The same is true for the `waist_size` entries.

**My question is this:**

Using PHP, how can I best consolidate this into a table that counts the total number of sizes, so that it could essentially be used as an **Order Form**?

For example, the MySQL table looks like this:

```
  ---------------------------------------------- 
  |     Name    |   shoe_size   |  waist_size  |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |      John   |      9.5      |      33      |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |     Steve   |       9       |      32      |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |     Tom     |      9.5      |      33      |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |    Sally    |       7       |       8      |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |    Jane     |       7       |       8      |
  ----------------------------------------------
```

And the output HTML (table?) would look something like this:

```
                ORDER FORM
  ------------------------------------------
  | Shoe Size     |   7   |   9   |   9.5  |
  ------------------------------------------
  | Total Pairs   |   2   |   1   |   2    |  <----- This is calculated from above
  ------------------------------------------

  ------------------------------------------
  | Waist Size    |   8   |   32   |   33  |
  ------------------------------------------
  | Total Pairs   |   2   |   1   |   2    |  <----- This is calculated from above
  ------------------------------------------
```

I'm not even sure if my format for the "Order Form" table is the best way to go on this.  Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL might be enough for this task, try something like

```
SELECT shoe_size, COUNT(id) as count FROM table GROUP BY shoe_size ORDER BY shoe_size asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is GROUP BY.
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

e.g:

```
SELECT `Shoe Size`, COUNT(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY `Shoe Size`
```